# JavaFX Integer Spinner (IntegerSpinnerValueFactory) does not wrap around the value to minimum

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

I have created an Integer Spinner with values

`min (5), max (15) and initialValue (12)` and `wrapAround (true)`.

Once the spinner reaches the `max (15)` value during increment, instead of resetting the value to `min (5)` as it says in the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SpinnerValueFactory.html#setWrapAround(boolean)), it is being reset to value `10 (max (15) - min (5))`

> public final void setWrapAround​(boolean value)
>
> Sets the value of the property wrapAround.
>
> **Property description:**
>
> The wrapAround property is used to specify whether the value factory should be circular. For example, should an integer-based value model increment from the maximum value back to the minimum value (and vice versa).

Note: Decrement works properly, once it reaches the `min (5)` value, Spinner value automatically set to `max (15)`

```
public class IntSpinnerTest extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
    var spinner = new Spinner<Integer>();

    var factory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(5, 15, 12);
    factory.setWrapAround(true);

    spinner.setValueFactory(factory);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(spinner), 400, 200));

    stage.setTitle("IntSpinnerTest");
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug: [JDK-8193286](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193286). The submitter included a workaround—subclassing `IntegerSpinnerValueFactory`:

```
package sample; 

import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory; 

public final class IntSpinnerValueFactory extends IntegerSpinnerValueFactory { 

  public IntSpinnerValueFactory(final int min, final int max) { 
    super(min, max); 
  } 

  public IntSpinnerValueFactory(final int min, final int max, final int initialValue) { 
    super(min, max, initialValue, 1); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public void increment(final int steps) { 
    final int min = getMin(); 
    final int max = getMax(); 
    final int currentValue = getValue(); 
    final int newIndex = currentValue + steps * getAmountToStepBy(); 
    setValue(newIndex <= max ? newIndex : (isWrapAround() ? (newIndex - min) % (max - min + 1) + min : max)); 
  } 

}
```

*Note: Workaround has been slightly modified based on recommendations.*

Comment: Looks like this is second bug in `SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory`. [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549829/javafx-spinner-empty-text-nullpointerexception/36570474#comment94547539_36570474) (They have fixed this `NullPointerException` bug in `DoubleSpinnerValueFactory` but not in `IntegerSpinnerValueFactory`.

Comment: There appears to be a workaround for this issue which I edited my answer to include.

Comment: Also, I took a look at the fix for the other bug you linked to. They definitely only fixed the problem for `DoubleSpinnerValueFactory`. There doesn't seem to be a way around it either as the problem is located in an internal property listener.

Comment: Bug submitter missed `final` once. In `increment()` method parameter .

Comment: You should change the last statement to `setValue(newIndex <= max ? newIndex : (isWrapAround() ? (newIndex - min) % (max - min + 1) + min : max));` make arbitrary permutations of `increment`/ `decrement` operations yield the same result. (Sorry, previous comment's version did not work `wrapAround = false`)

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problem with IntegerSpinner - but wrapping from -11 to 12 (negative to positive) - on reaching -11 or 12 it returns to zero. Solution was to make List spinner with Strings. So that using or setting the values I've needed to convert string to integer and vc.