# Spinner Integer value not updating after direct input from the UI

Tags: javafx, spinner, fxml

I'm wondering how to set the value of a JavaFX Spinner directly from the UI. As I have it now, I have to use the buttons up and down to change it, when I set directly it's not being updated.

I know with Swing you can just use spinner#setValue but it seems to be different with JavaFX.

**Fxml:**

```
<Spinner fx:id="spinnerClusters" editable="true" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="107.0">
    <HBox.margin>
        <Insets left="10.0" />
    </HBox.margin>
</Spinner>
```

**Controller:**

```
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            spinnerClusters.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 100, 0));      
        }
////
    int value = spinnerNBClusters.getValue();
```

How can I make the value change if the user inputs it directly into the spinner field?

Comment: Press "Enter". It's a bug in Java 8, should be fixed in 9:  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150946 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually typing in text in JavaFX Spinner is not updating the value (unless user presses ENTER)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340476/manually-typing-in-text-in-javafx-spinner-is-not-updating-the-value-unless-user)

Answer (score 0):

As sillyfly draw my attention to, it is a bug in Java 8.

The solution is to press "Enter".

It should be fixed in Java 9:

> bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150946